# Android multi flavor library referenced from non flavor application - AAPT: No resource found

Tags: android, gradle, android-productflavors

I have library which contains string resource:

```
<string name="lib_name">MyLibrary</string>
```

Reference to library in application build.gradle:

```
dependencies{
  compile project(':mylibrary')
...
}
```

In application module I have displayed this text resource:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lib_name" />
```

There is no problem without using flavors.
Now I want to add new flavor to library with different text.

build.gradle of library:

```
android {
...
  productFlavors {
    myFlavor {}
  }
}
```

Then I create new resource file for new flavor \mylibrary\src\myFlavor\res\values\strings.xml:

```
<string name="lib_name">MyLibrary My Flavor</string>
```

But now I have build error, resource is not available anymore:

```
AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/lib_name').
```

I need this application has only default flavor. Resource in 'myFlavor' will be consumed in different application, which will also have 'myFlavor' flavor specified.

What I need to change in application to solve this error?

Thank you for any help.

Edit:
I uploaded my sample project [here](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/3Mk1iRCPrtjJVxaMHbLA8h0VQZL0hewTqdLNlsBAGqb).

Comment: What build.gradle file do you have the flavors defined?

Comment: In build.gradle of library module (it is written in my question above). Application module has no flavor defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, change flavor configuration to your dependency:

```
compile project(path: ':mylibrary', configuration: 'myFlavorRelease')
```

Secondly, replace your wrong AndroidManifest.xml in *mylibrary\src\myFlavor* by correct in *mylibrary\src\main*.