# Can library depends and reads resources from another multi flavored library?

Tags: android, libraries, android-productflavors, android-build-flavors, android-flavors

Using: Android Studio 3.2.1 - Gradle 4.6

I have an app with 3 modules: :app :lib1 (library) :lib2 (library)
:app depends from lib1 and lib2 :lib 1 depends from lib2
lib2 is a module containing only resources (res folder for images, strings, colors and values in general, not java code) referenced from both :app and :lib1

I want to flavor :app module and :lib2 module with same flavors (for customize apps for my customers specifyng a different package for every app). :lib1 has no flavor

Before add flavors all works right.
I added 1 flavor to :app module and to :lib2 module called "client1".
I added to :lib2 a "client1" folder in :lib2\src\client1.

Gradle compile created related build variants for: 
:app-client1Debug 
:app-client1Release 
:lib1-Debug 
:lib1-Release 
:lib2-client1Debug 
:lib2-client1Release

I run debug build variant and app was installed right and succesfully takes right resources from client1 flavor in :lib2 module

Now i added a second flavor i.e. "client2" to :app and :lib2 modules, and a folder in ":lib2\src\client2" for resources of flavor for second customer customization.
I added productFlavors and configurations and relative dependencies in gradle file of :app and :lib1 for the library module :lib2

```
    APP MODULE GRADLE FILE
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "it.test.myapp" 
     .
     .

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        client1 {
            dimension="default"
            versionNameSuffix "-client1"
            applicationIdSuffix ".client1"
        }
        client2 {
            dimension="default"
            versionNameSuffix "-client2"
            applicationIdSuffix ".client2"
        }
    }
    }
    configurations { 
        client1DefaultDebugCompile 
        client1DefaultReleaseCompile 
        client2DefaultDebugCompile 
        client2DefaultReleaseCompile 
   }

   dependencies { 
    // implementation project(':lib2') //before flavors
    implementation project(':lib1')

    client1DefaultDebugCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'client1Debug')
    client1DefaultReleaseCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'client1Release')

    client2DefaultDebugCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'client2Debug')
    client2DefaultReleaseCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'client2Release')


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation ....
    . . .
    }


:lib1 MODULE GRADLE FILE

    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    android { 

       ....some configuration
    defaultConfig {
       ...some configuration

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
           'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }
    configurations { 
         client1DefaultDebugCompile 
         client1DefaultReleaseCompile 
         client2DefaultDebugCompile 
         client2DefaultReleaseCompile 
    }
    dependencies { 
         //implementation project(':lib2') //before flavors
         client1DefaultDebugCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'client1Debug')
         client1DefaultReleaseCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'client1Release')

         client2DefaultDebugCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'client2tDebug')
         client2DefaultReleaseCompile project(path: ':lib2', configuration: 'client2Release')


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation ...
     ....some implementation
    }


:lib2 MODULE GRADLE FILE

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {

publishNonDefault true

...some config



defaultConfig {
   ...some config

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    client1 {
        dimension="default"
    }
    client2 {
        dimension="default"
    }
}
}

dependencies { implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
...some implementation
}
```

I expected that both :app and :lib1 module take right flavored version of :lib2 module resources.
I sync gradle with build variants on: 
:app-client1Debug 
:lib1-Debug //Has no flavor 
:lib2-client1Debug

and gradle sync process ends with an exception:
:app:processClient1DebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    •   What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processClient1DebugResources'.Android resource linking failed Output: /Users/davide/Documents/......./android/MyApp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeClient1DebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:2601: error: resource color/colorPrimary (aka it.test.myapp.client1:color/colorPrimary) not found.

and other similar error linking other resources that :lib1 should takes from :lib2 client1 flavor.

It seems :lib1 package isn't able to read those resources
If i try to rebuild from menu "Build->Rebuild Project" i get a similar error:

:lib1:javaPreCompileDebug    /Users/davide/Documents/...../android/MyApp/lib1/src/main/java/it/test/lib1/utils/Utils.java:183: error: cannot find symbol textView.setTextColor(MyApplication.getInstance().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)); ^ symbol: variable colorPrimaryDark location: class color
    ....
    .....
/Users/davide/Documents/......../android/MyApp/lib1/src/main/java/it/test/lib1/utils/Utils.java:228: error: cannot find symbol String channelId = context.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id); ^ symbol: variable default_notification_channel_id location: class string 
    .
    . ....other similar error 
    .
    .
    .
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 50 errors :lib1:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        •   What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':lib1:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.      
        •   Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

---

If i select build variants on 
:app-client2Debug 
:lib1-Debug //Has no flavor 
:lib2-client2Debug

I have the same errors for client2 flavor and :lib1 cant read those resources.
Now sould someone point me to the right solution? Can a library have a dependency and read resources from another FLAVORED library?
I read this https://android.jlelse.eu/product-flavors-for-android-library-d3b2d240fca2
and this https://proandroiddev.com/advanced-android-flavors-part-1-building-white-label-apps-on-android-ade16af23bcf
and this one [Android multi flavor library referenced from non flavor application - AAPT: No resource found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658325/android-multi-flavor-library-referenced-from-non-flavor-application-aapt-no-r)
and others...and i though i was right...but....not works

//UPDATE
If I remove flavors from :lib2 gradle file and dependency flavor configuration of it from :app and :lib1 but mantaining :app module with the two flavors on, app runs and was installed for boh variants and with correct versionNameSuffix for this i think i'm missing something in configuration of :lib1 to make it able to read resources from correct flavor of :lib2.

Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: can you share a project with this configuration on github?

Answer (score 0):

Your request, Is not feasible. As usual the library don't use internal resource of other library but use the library-API, and the resources are accessed via package name, if your flawor change it remember to change every reference from other library. Not use the flawor path on the other references.